# NullPointerException when onLoadFinished callback is reached

Tags: android

I looked at the other SO posts and none seemed to solve my probleman (the cursor in the onCreateLoader callback has an _id projection, which fixed the problem in another question on here). From the looks of it, I've initialized my database and hooked everything up properly.

Fragment (initializing mSpinnerAdapter):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        int[] toViews = {R.id.spinner_top, R.id.spinner_bottom};

        mSpinnerAdapter = new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                null,
                null,
                toViews,
                0
        );
        mSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner topYearSpinner =
                (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_year_top);
        topYearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner bottomYearSpinner =
                (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_year_bottom);
        bottomYearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        topYearSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
        bottomYearSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
```

DBHelper:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String CREATE__TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                Contract.Entry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                Contract.Entry.COLUMN_YEAR + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                Contract.Entry.COLUMN.OTHER_ + " INTEGER, " +
                Contract.Entry.COLUMN.OTHER1_ + " INTEGER);";

        //Building the table
        db.execSQL(CREATE__TABLE);
    }
```

LoaderCallbacks:

```
@Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String[] projection = {Contract.Entry._ID, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_YEAR};
        String sortOrder = Contract.Entry.COLUMN_YEAR + " ASC";

        return new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                Contract.Entry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mSpinnerAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mSpinnerAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

ContentProvider:

```
public class Provider extends ContentProvider{

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    private DbHelper mDbHelper;

    static final int _INDICES = 100;

    public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = Contract.AUTHORITY;

        matcher.addURI(authority, "_indices", _INDICES);

        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }
```

Contract:

```
public class Contract {

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.kent.mojito";
    public static final String PATH__INDICES = "_indices";
    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);

    public static final class Entry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH__INDICES).build();

        public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE+ "/" + AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH__INDICES;
        public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH__INDICES;

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "_indices";
        public static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "year";
        public static final String COLUMN_ = "";
        public static final String COLUMN_ = "";

        //Building a query for the Provider insert statement
        static Uri buildIndicesUri (long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-15 17:26:13.845  24281-24281/com.example.kent.mojito E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kent.mojito, PID: 24281
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:328)
            at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:345)
            at com.example.kent.mojito.ValueFragment.onLoadFinished(ValueFragment.java:133)
            at com.example.kent.mojito.ValueFragment.onLoadFinished(ValueFragment.java:35)
            at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:427)
            at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:395)
            at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:104)
            at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:73)
            at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:35)
            at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:223)
            at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
            at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:461)
            at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$500(ModernAsyncTask.java:47)
            at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:474)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How mSpinnerAdapter is initialized? add the code

Comment: Well you need to debug onLoadFinished and see what elements there are null. Could be data, could be adapter

Comment: Added code showing how mSpinnerAdapter is initialized.

Comment: I believe the adapter is null; I called data.getColumnCount, which came back with an int value of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your initialization is not well at all, if you have a look to the SimpleCursorAdapter code, the swap method is:

```
public void changeCursorAndColumns(Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    mOriginalFrom = from;
    mTo = to;
    // super.changeCursor() will notify observers before we have
    // a valid mapping, make sure we have a mapping before this
    // happens
    findColumns(c, mOriginalFrom);
    super.changeCursor(c);
}
```

The line 345 is calling to findColumns with c coming from your onLoadFinished method and in that case 'data', but, mOriginalFrom passed to findColumsn is null because in the initialization of your SimpleCursorAdapter you are passing null in the fourth argument. You can have a better idea reading the consturctor of SimpleCursorAdapter, copied below:

```
 public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, flags);
    mTo = to;
    mOriginalFrom = from;
    findColumns(c, from);
}
```

Reading the source of SimpleCursorAdapter, the only place where mOriginalFrom is changed is calling to the method changeCursorAndColumns.